# How can I script the replacement of multiple lines of unique text?

Tags: scripting

I run a server that, when I update, I have to reconfigure all the prompts in their respective source files again. There are several hundred, if not over 1,000 lines that I end up having to reconfigure in order to get the server functioning as desired every update. It takes nearly three days to update, and two of those days are spent doing just that.

I'm looking for a way to replace (for example) "godmodemsg: You have been godded." on line 30 with "godmodemsg: Your forcefield is now active" , as well as several other lines that are different. I need it to be able to replace it if the line, say, changes to line 53 as well. Most of this is done in a normal text file. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Questions asking to recommend a tool or library are off topic for SO and will likely be closed.  However, it sounds like  you just need a find replace method in whatever compiler you're using.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -e 's/You have been godded./Your forcefield is now active/g' /dir/yourfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If the version of sed you have does not support the -i (in place) option you'll have to redirect the output to a temporary file and then do a mv from the temporary file to the original one. Be careful, you should cat the temporary file first to check if the result of the replacement was what you expected.